# Using a C# HttpWebRequest's HttpWebResponse variable from Web-Service in if statement

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I have a C# Windows Form Application, sending variables to a PHP web-service.

Tested separately:

1) The PHP Web-Service works and return result.

2) The C# Windows Form Application to display variables in the URL with `WebRequest`, the variables are displayed correctly in the URL.

3) When I display the return variable in C# using a `MessageBox.Show`, the correct variable display (Allow)

[image]

But, when I use the return variable in an `if` statement it does not execute the code inside the `if`statement.

[image]

Here is my PHP Web-Service:

```
<?php
// Database Structure 
require_once('connect.php');

//Get password from the database for the user

$stmtus = $conn->prepare("SELECT password from `Users` where `email` = :Username");
$stmtus->bindParam(':Username', $username);
$username= $_GET['username'];;
$stmtus -> execute();
$password = $stmtus->fetch();

$un = $_GET['username'];
$pw = $_GET['password'];
$ust = $_GET['Token'];

if(password_verify($pw, $password[0])){
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT 
COUNT(Token) AS cnt FROM `SoftwareToken` 
LEFT JOIN User ON iduser = SoftwareToken.Consultant 
WHERE Token = :Token 
AND username = :Username");
$stmt->bindValue(':Username', $un);
$stmt->bindValue(':Token', $ust);
$stmt->execute();
$result= array();
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$cnt = $result['cnt'];
if($cnt == 1){
    echo "Allow";
}else{
    echo "NO";
} 
?>
```

Here is my C# Windows Form Application code:

```
        private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtusername.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please insert username");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtpassword.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please insert password");
        }
        var Token = "PYPYY 46355 R8T2Q2";
        var username = txtusername.Text;
        var password = txtpassword.Text;
        var url = "https://mydomain.com.au/LoginVerification.php?";
        var var = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&Token=" + Token;
        var URL = url + var;
        // MessageBox.Show(URL);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.  
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);
        // Display the content.  

        if (responseFromServer == "Allow")
        {
            //Form1 identykidzform = new Form1();
            //identykidzform.Show();
            MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);
        }
        else if (responseFromServer == "NO")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No");
            //Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test failed");
            //Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the `responseFromServer` when it fails? And you are missing two closing brackets in the PHP file.

Comment: You could try to investigate better reading the responseFromServer variable. If it fails is because the response is nor "Allow" nor "NO"

Comment: You are consuming a service with HTTPS endpoint . Be sure you get a valid response without an error.

Comment: *"it does not execute the code inside the if statement"* - Then the `if` condition is `false`.  Debug and observe the exact values of your variables.  Are they what you expect them to be?  Is there any errant whitespace or anything else in the string which would cause it to not be *exactly* what you're comparing it with?

Comment: I don't know php but can `$result['cnt']` throw an exception?

Comment: @Nilesh only if there's no index named "cnt" in the $result associative array. But there _should_ be, because that's the column alias used in the SQL query